# Redirect 'print' to STDOUT?

Tags: console, rebol, io-redirection

How can I make Rebol output "Hello world!" string to standard output? I tried with `rebol.exe -w --do "print [\"Hello world!\"]"` but I don't see any output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in R3  You need to get the experimental console version for this to work:

http://www.rebolsource.net/

in R2, you need to add the -c option like so:

rebol.exe -cw --do "print [\"Hello world!\"]"

-c stands for cgi mode

Comment: I still don't get anyting in R2, it works however in R3 (r3-gfc51038-console.exe). Thanks!

Comment: ah yes, with R2 you need to use the SDK to build yourself a console mode binary.  but you can also try this: `rebol.exe -qc --do "print [\"Hello world!\"] halt" | more`  note I added a `HALT` at the end, to prevent the banner (seems the -q options doesn't work in the latest binary).